# What percentage of prime number factorials plus 1 are themselves prime?

Tags: prime-numbers

One of the steps in Euclid's proof of the infinity of primes is sometimes misinterpreted to be a way of generating new prime numbers. Specifically constructing the number P!+1 where P is a prime is sometimes though to guarantee a new prime by naive students.

But what is the ratio of prime factorials plus one that are *actually* prime (and does this ratio tend to a known limit)?

It is worth adding that, as far as I can tell (see [this](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Factorial_prime)) only 4 such numbers are known to be primes so the ratio is likely to be *very* small!

Comment: A possibly naive response: Doesn't the factorial function just grow too fast for the ratio $\frac{|\{p\leq n : p\text{ is a prime of the form }m!+1\}|}{|\{p \leq n : p \text{ is a prime}\}|}$ to tend to anything other than $0$? The denominator grows at a rate of $n/\log n$ but doesn't the numerator grow extremely slowly?

Comment: @James Possibly. But I'm interested to see whether anything is known for sure and I'm not much of a mathematician.

Comment: The OEIS sequences https://oeis.org/A088332 and https://oeis.org/A002981 are relevant.  The sequence looks sparse enough that I'd guess the density is 0.  The paper by Caldwell and Gallot at http://www.utm.edu/staff/caldwell/preprints/primorials.pdf gives a heuristic (Conjecture 2.3) that the number of primes $n! + 1$ with $n \le N$ is asymptotic to $e^\gamma \log N$ as $N \to \infty$.

Comment: Suppose that, for sufficiently large $p,$ $p!+1$ is never a prime?

Comment: It's not an arithmetic sequence and I'm pretty sure it's an open question whether there are infinitely many primes of this form.